# Using JSON with a web service on ServiceStack

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, servicestack

I am having a little difficulty in understanding how to use JSON with entity framework and web services (ServiceStack):

Suppose I have one entity:

```
public class Report
{
    public int IdReport {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

So It's not recommended to send this object, since this object is from Model layer, and I am using ServiceStack which encourages the use of DTO. I will probably need two more classes:

```
public class ReportRequest
{
    public idReport {get;set;}
}

public class ReportResponse
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Is this correct? How can I use JSON to parse the values over HTTP. Suppose I need to send a report to be inserted into database, would I need one more object? Or Could I send a JSON formatted with the two properties `idReport` and `Name`?

Comment: What did google say? No links to any blogs?

Comment: I just found this [link](http://rlacovara.blogspot.com.br/2009/03/what-is-difference-between-dto-and-poco.html). It shows something really good. You can you DTO inside POCO, so you do not need extra properties being created repeatedly

Comment: Why you are using EF? Haven't you tried Ormlite?

Comment: I have a long experience with EF and I found a little difficult migrate to ormlite. Can you provide me some example of how this could be better ?